# Mutex lock and write to file

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I'm trying to write some data to a file if a condition is met. 
The function which contains all this is accessed by multiple threads.

Each time the condition is met, there are four variables that are written "A, B, C, D". It happens more often than not that the datafile to which it is written to has more variables that it should contain in a single line.

After a bit of debugging through gdb I realised that multiple threads are writing at the same time, and which is why I introduced a pthread mutex lock.

```
void Client::response(Sender* send, FILE *fp){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);    

    if (status == ROI) {           

        if (condition) {
            RPS=serviceTime.size();
            double q90, q95, q99 = 0.0;
            std::sort(serviceTime.begin(), serviceTime.end());
            int q90 = (int)ceil(0.90 * double(RPS));
            int q95 = (int)ceil(0.95 * double(RPS));
            int q99 = (int)ceil(0.99 * double(RPS));
            q90 = serviceTime.at(Index90-1)/1e6;
            q95 = serviceTime.at(Index95-1)/1e6;
            q99 = serviceTime.at(Index99-1)/1e6;
            fprintf(fp, "%d, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f\n", RPS, q90, q95, q99);
            fflush(fp);
            serviceTime.clear();
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

What am I missing here? why is it written multiple times to the same file?

Comment: Where is `lock` defined? Where is `fp` used other than here? We need an MCVE.

Comment: High-level. FP is not used anywhere else other than here. The lock is defined in the Client class.  and response is a public funciton. 
Working on MCVE - will generate it

Comment: Check the return value of `pthread_mutex_lock`? Need more code.. I think.

Comment: Are the threads using multiple objects of Client class or the same object? Need MCVE.

Comment: I'm modifying this particular function (https://github.com/chyyuu/tailbench/blob/master/harness/client.cpp#L119) Will create MCVE anyway. Let me also run through gdb line by line.

Comment: Are there several client object or just one client object? If there are several clients, maybe make the mutex a static object otherwise each client will have its own lock but you need the mutex to work on a single lock to work. Also, consider locking only if the condition is met i.e. moving the lock inside the condition if.

Comment: Any special reason why you chose a C implementation of a thread library instead of using standard C++ threads? If something throws while you're holding one of those `pthread` locks, it won't be unlocked. I suggest using a `std::mutex` and a `std::lock_guard` instead. What resource are you protecting? Is it only the `FILE*`?

Comment: I made a pretty dumb mistake. one instance of the file is opened for each thread, and that's the for some lines I had more lines than others. I fixed that now by moving it here (https://github.com/chyyuu/tailbench/blob/master/harness/client.cpp#L54) from here (https://github.com/chyyuu/tailbench/blob/master/harness/tbench_client_networked.cpp#L48)

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest looking at either [conditional vars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until), which are used to wait until a condition is verified or [scoped locks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) that lock the resources in the scope until you exit said scope.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Neither of these things will help based on the OP question details.

Comment: Multiple threads are writing to the same file, I see a condition at the top of the function, that screams cond vars ... But ok

Comment: Maybe, or maybe you don't wan't to block in this function except to wait for other threads to write. The point is, you don't know based on the details in the question. Your answer is very very general and doesn't solve the problem being asked about.

Comment: Well, the question is very very vague, and I believe the solution is contained in the concepts I linked. But please, be my guest and find a better one :)
I would think that for any concurrent writes to a shared resource, those concepts are key.

Comment: Sure ... But when we question is vague we comment and ask or more details, not just answer very vaguely. Plus, the OP is using mutex already, which is the concept for insuring exclusive access, not condition vars. Plus they are using pthread, which will not work with the links you provided, perhaps they don't have c++11.

Comment: I agree that they don't necessarily use C++11 (that'd be strange nowadays, but sure).
For your comment, I simply didn't see it.
And yes, they are using mutexes, but it apparently doesn't work, so maybe a more appropriate / standard approach to the mentioned problem of waiting for a condition to be met to run a concurrent piece of code is a good pointer.
If OP doesn't agree, I believe he can say it himself :)